# Why does automatic conversion from const to non-const & occur when setting a class member?

Tags: c++, oop

The following code compiles and works. Why doesn't it produce an error: "cannot convert from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &'"?

```
class Test {
private:
    std::string& _str;
public:
    Test(std::string& str) : _str(str)
    { }

    void SetStr(const std::string& str)
    {
        // std::string& s = str; // error: cannot convert from 'const std::string' to 'std::string &'

        _str = str; // strange, but it works!
        _str.append(", world!"); // it works too
    }

    const std::string& GetStr()
    {
        return _str;
    }
};
```

...

```
std::string str = "";
Test test(str);

test.SetStr("Hello");

std::cout << test.GetStr(); // prints "Hello, world!"
std::cout << str; // also prints "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing [*initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) and [*assignment*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

`_str = str;` is an assignment, [`std::string::operator=(const std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) will be called, `str` is fine as the argument. That means the value of the object `_str` being bound to will be changed, not the reference itself. For the same reason `_str.append(", world!");` is fine too.

While `std::string& s = str;` is a reference initialization, it fails because can't bind a const to non-const reference.

Answer (score 1):

Once a reference have been initialized, it always references that object it has been initialized with, you can't reassign a reference variable.

When you do the assignment `_str = str` in the `SetStr` function, you don't change the reference, you change the object it references, which is not a constant object.

---

Simple example:

```
std::string string1 = "foo";
std::string const string2 = "bar";

std::string& string_ref = string1;  // string_ref now is a reference of string1

string_ref = string2;  // Doesn't change what string_ref references,
                       // instead changes string1

std::cout << string1 << '\n';  // Will output "bar"
```